# Increment list indexes to get correct values to be updated in XML data based on Title

Tags: python, xml, beautifulsoup

List elements to be appended in XML data:

```
Sorted_TestSpecID: [10860972, 10860972, 10860972, 10860972, 10860972]
Sorted_TestCaseID: [16961435, 16961462, 16961739, 16961741, 16961745]
Sorted_TestText  : ['SIG1', 'SIG2', 'SIG3', 'Signal1', 'Signal2']
```

original xml data:

```
<tc>
  <title>Signal1</title>
  <tcid>2c758925-dc3d-4b1d-a5e2-e0ca54c52a47</tcid>
  <attributes>
    <attr>
      <key>TestSpec ID</key>
      <value>0</value>
    </attr>
    <attr>
      <key>TestCase ID</key>
      <value>0</value>
    </attr>
  </attributes>
</tc>
```

Trying Python script to:

Search title Signal1 in xml data from Sorted_TestText
Then it should search for Key =TestCase ID and update the corresponding 16961741 value
Then it shall check for its resp. Key =TestSpec ID and update the corresponding 10860972.

```
soup = BeautifulSoup(xml_data, 'xml') 

for tc in soup.find_all('tc'):
    for title, spec, case in zip(Sorted_TestText, Sorted_TestSpecID, Sorted_TestCaseID):    
        if tc.find('title').text == title:
            for attr in tc.find_all('attr'):
                if attr.find('key').text == "TestSpec ID":
                    attr.find('value').text = str(spec)
                if attr.find('key').text == "TestCase ID"
                    attr.find('value').text = str(case)

print(soup)
```

I've tried above script ,this script is not updating spec and case based on title, working on if spec, case and title are in order. My intention was script shall look for title and then it shall update its respective attributes. Lets say in my xml 'SIG1', 'SIG2', 'SIG3' are not present; I want to update spec and case of Signal1 with spec: 10860972 case: 16961741, but with this script it is updating SIG4 as spec: 10860972 case: 16961435. Need to traverse the spec and case lists as well for respective title. I tried, but no luck.; Required support here. Thanks in advance.

Comment: can you share url of the page

Answer (score 0):

I'd use a dictionary where keys are titles and values are TestCaseIDs and TestSpecIDs.

Then, to change the contents of `<value>` use `.string` instead of `.text`:

```py
dct = {
    c: (str(a), str(b))
    for a, b, c in zip(Sorted_TestSpecID, Sorted_TestCaseID, Sorted_TestText)
}


for tc in soup.select("tc"):
    title = tc.title.get_text(strip=True)
    if title not in dct:
        continue

    val = tc.select_one('attr:has(key:-soup-contains("TestSpec ID")) value')
    if val:
        val.string = str(dct[title][0])

    val = tc.select_one('attr:has(key:-soup-contains("TestCase ID")) value')
    if val:
        val.string = str(dct[title][1])

print(soup.prettify())
```

Prints:

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<tc>
 <title>
  Signal1
 </title>
 <tcid>
  2c758925-dc3d-4b1d-a5e2-e0ca54c52a47
 </tcid>
 <attributes>
  <attr>
   <key>
    TestSpec ID
   </key>
   <value>
    10860972
   </value>
  </attr>
  <attr>
   <key>
    TestCase ID
   </key>
   <value>
    16961741
   </value>
  </attr>
 </attributes>
</tc>
```